# ¿Cómo colocar una condición dentro de return en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<aside className={`${styles.contenido_curso}`}>
            <h3>Contenido del curso</h3>
            <div className="wrapper">
              <div className="accordion">
                {modulos.map((item, i) => (
                  <div className="item" key={i}>
                    <div className="title" onClick={() => toggle(i)}>
                      <span className="arrow">
                        {selected === i ? "-" : "+"}
                      </span>
                      <h3>
                        Módulo {item.id_modulo}: {item.titulo_modulo}
                      </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      className={selected === i ? "content show" : "content"}
                    >
                      {item.videos.map((video, j) => (
                        <p
                          onClick={() => pasarVideo(item.videos[j])}
                          id={video.url_video}
                          key={j}
                          disabled
                        >
                          {video.titulo_video}
                        </p>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </aside>
```

En donde mapea por un lado, los módulos y por otro, los videos de los módulos. Yo quisiera agregar una condición en esta parte:

```
{item.videos.map((video, j) => (
     <p
     onClick={() => pasarVideo(item.videos[j])}
     id={video.url_video}
     key={j}
     >
     {video.titulo_video}
     </p>
))}
```

En donde diga que si item.videos.videoDesbloqueado == true me muestre esto:

```
{item.videos.map((video, j) => (
         <p
         onClick={() => pasarVideo(item.videos[j])}
         id={video.url_video}
         key={j}
         >
         {video.titulo_video}
         </p>
))}
```

**PD**: el array de videos tiene una propiedad videoDesbloqueado.

Y sino que me muestre botones con el atributo disabled, ya que los videos estarían bloqueados, ¿cómo podría agregar esta condición? No logro sacarlo ya que tengo un .map en medio y se me complica (soy nuevo en React). Muchas gracias!

```
{item.videos.map((video, j) => (
         <button
         disabled
         onClick={() => pasarVideo(item.videos[j])}
         id={video.url_video}
         key={j}
         >
         {video.titulo_video}
         </nutton>
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar un [operador condicional (ternario)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) dentro del `.map()` para mostrar el elemento según corresponda.

> El operador condicional (ternario) es el único operador en JavaScript
> que tiene tres operandos. Este operador se usa con frecuencia como
> atajo para la instrucción if.

```
condición ? expr1 : expr2
```

En tu caso tu código quedaría algo así:

```
{item.videos.map((video, j) => (
  video.videoDesbloqueado ? (
    <p
      onClick={() => pasarVideo(item.videos[j])}
      id={video.url_video}
      key={j}
    >
      {video.titulo_video}
    </p>
  ) : (
    <button
      disabled
      onClick={() => pasarVideo(item.videos[j])}
      id={video.url_video}
      key={j}
    >
      {video.titulo_video}
    </button>
  )
))}
```